# Every zero-mean Lévy process has linear variance (wrt $t$)

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, levy-processes

I'd like to show that every Lévy process with $\mathbb{E}X_t=0, \:\forall t\ge0$ has linear variance, namely $t\mapsto\mathbb{E}X^2_t$ is linear. I showed that indeed the additivity holds, i.e. $t+s\mapsto\mathbb{E}X^2_s+\mathbb{E}X^2_t$, but I still have some problem in showing the homogeneity, i.e. $at\mapsto a\mathbb{E}X_t^2$.

That's my attempt

$t+s\mapsto E[X_t^2]+E[X_s^2]$, in fact

\begin{align}
E[X_{t+s}^2]=&E[(X_{t+s}-X_s+X_s)^2]\\
=&E[(X_t-X_s)^2+X_s^2+2X_s(X_{t+s}-X_s)]\\
=&E[(X_t+X_s)^2]+E[X_s^2]+2E[X_{s}(X_{t+s}-X_s)]\\
=&E[X_t^2]+E[X_s^2]+2E[X_s]E[X_{t+s}-X_s]\\
=&E[X_t^2]+E[X_s^2]+2E[X_s]E[X_{t}]\\
=&E[X_t^2]+E[X_s^2]
\end{align}

Regarding the homogeneity, it is equivalent to show that for every $t>0$ one has
$t\mapsto tE[X^2_1]$, but doing the computation iteratively I cannot manage to obtain the desired result.

Any help is appreciated. Tnx

Comment: One possibility is to show $\mathbb{E}(X_{t}^2) = t \mathbb{E}(X_1^2)$ for all $t \in \mathbb{Q}$ and then extend the identity using continuity.

Comment: Thanks! I managed to show it for $t\in\mathbb{Q}$ but actually it's not clear to me how the homogeneity for $t\in\mathbb{R}$ follows...

Comment: Do you assume that $\mathbb{E}(X_t^2)<\infty$ for all $t$?

Comment: I think I've to assume it. In the case $\mathbb{E}(X_t^2)=\infty$ for some $t>0$, then $\mathbb{E}(X_t^2)=\infty$, $\forall t\ge0$ by the additivity and the linearity follows trivially. While the other case is not trivial. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints:**

1. It suffices to consider the case that $\mathbb{E}(X_t^2)<\infty$ for all $t \geq 0$.
2. Show that $\mathbb{E}(X_t^2) = t \mathbb{E}(X_1^2)$ for any $t \in \mathbb{Q} \cap [0,\infty)$ using the additivity you have already shown. (Hint: write $t= \frac{m}{n}$ for $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$.)
3. Fix arbitrary $t \in [0,\infty)$ and a sequence $(t_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq \mathbb{Q} \cap [0,T]$ such that $t_n \downarrow t$. As $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a martingale, it follows from Doob's inequality that $\sup_{s \in [0,T]} X_s^2 \in L^1$. Using the right-continuity of $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ and the dominated convergence theorem, we get $$\mathbb{E}(X_t^2) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E}(X_{t_n}^2) \stackrel{t_n \in \mathbb{Q}}{=} \lim_{n \to \infty} t_n \mathbb{E}(X_1^2) = t \mathbb{E}(X_1^2).$$

Comment: Thank you very much! If I understood it properly, in your point 3 you used the right-continuity+ Doob $L^p$ inequality + dominated convergence in the first equality, the linearity $\forall t\in\mathbb{Q}$ in the second one, and the fact that $t_n\downarrow t$ in the third one. Am I right?

Comment: @sharon Yes, exactly.